# order sql query by name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nopcommerce

I have a query which I would like to tweak little bit to display different info. 
Currently my query gets all the orders with products ranked by the one with most conversions at the top. 
Here is the query:

```
   SELECT nopv.ProductVariantID, COUNT(nopv.ProductVariantID), p.ProductId, c.CategoryID, c.Name FROM Nop_OrderProductVariant nopv
INNER JOIN Nop_ProductVariant npv
ON nopv.ProductVariantID = npv.ProductVariantId
INNER JOIN Nop_Product p
ON npv.ProductID = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN Nop_Product_Category_Mapping npcm
ON p.ProductId = npcm.ProductID
INNER JOIN Nop_Category c 
ON npcm.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
GROUP BY nopv.ProductVariantID, p.ProductId, c.CategoryID, c.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(nopv.ProductVariantID) DESC
```

What I have as a result is:

[image]

I want to be able to have each category only one time, for example "programmers & modules" category should only one record, containing the sum of all the productvariantIDs in that category. The first field can be avoided as well, because if there are multiple productvariants, the query will need to show just one. What I really need is the count of each category and the categoryID. 
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: query doesnt match with result set. what is that (No Column Name)?

Comment: @StingyJack query updated, sorry

Comment: The subject of your question doesn't match the content. Do you need to change the ordering?

Comment: Can you show what you want the results to look like, instead of trying to describe it? If you only want one row for `Programmers & Modules`, for example, what do you want the other columns to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is your `group by`:

```
GROUP BY nopv.ProductVariantID, p.ProductId, c.CategoryID, c.Name
```

Try:

```
GROUP BY c.CategoryID, c.Name -- c.Name is here since you probably can't select it otherwise
```

Then make whatever changes you need to your `SELECT` so it will work.

So something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(nopv.ProductVariantID), c.CategoryID, c.Name
FROM Nop_OrderProductVariant nopv
INNER JOIN Nop_ProductVariant npv
ON nopv.ProductVariantID = npv.ProductVariantId
INNER JOIN Nop_Product p
ON npv.ProductID = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN Nop_Product_Category_Mapping npcm
ON p.ProductId = npcm.ProductID
INNER JOIN Nop_Category c 
ON npcm.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
GROUP BY c.CategoryID, c.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(nopv.ProductVariantID) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both your and @JamieF answers were correct but you were faster.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the Variant and ProductID from both the select and Group By.

```
   SELECT
     COUNT(nopv.ProductVariantID) ,
     c.CategoryID ,
     c.Name
   FROM
     Nop_OrderProductVariant nopv
   INNER JOIN Nop_ProductVariant npv
   ON
     nopv.ProductVariantID = npv.ProductVariantId
   INNER JOIN Nop_Product p
   ON
     npv.ProductID = p.ProductId
   INNER JOIN Nop_Product_Category_Mapping npcm
   ON
     p.ProductId = npcm.ProductID
   INNER JOIN Nop_Category c
   ON
     npcm.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
   GROUP BY
     c.CategoryID ,
     c.Name
   HAVING
     COUNT(*) > 0
   ORDER BY
     COUNT(nopv.ProductVariantID) DESC
```